# Why hasn't this question been automatically deleted as RemoveAbandonedClosed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, automatic-deletion

From [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) in the Help Center:

> If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed",
>   and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39311155/3853934) meets the above requirements, but is not deleted (update: it has been deleted by three delete votes). Is it a bug in roomba?

Here are other questions where this happened: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30469228/1743880) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17182685/1743880) (deleted manually now) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36453134/1743880) (deleted by the roomba, but well after the date it should have been).

Comment: It's because the `CreateRemoveAbandonedClosedFactoryFactory` hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: The roomba had a hiccup about a month ago and didn't run for a while; I wonder if that occurred again.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Actually it was, but it triggered the `RemoveCreateAbandonedClosedFactoryFactoryFactory` with obvious results.

Comment: This reminds me: has anyone filed a bug report that the actual banner on roombad posts says `RemovedAbandonedClosed`, with "remove**d**"? It's been bugging me more than it should.

Comment: @AndrasDeak nope, nobody has.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: \*ducks the giant D swinging toward you\*

Comment: @NathanTuggy Jeff never said no nothing about no verb tense/mode bug reports;)

Comment: @NathanTuggy If one was unfamiliar with a certain post of Jeff's, your comment could be misunderstood in a childish, yet still hilarious way.

Comment: @That1Guy you just shattered a man innocent dream :(

Comment: @Oded Why remove the bug tag?

Comment: @Tunaki - because it isn't a coding issue. This is a self-fixing problem.

Comment: @Oded If a script is timing out, there is an issue that needs fixing (updated / corrected / optimized). The bug may be more general (DB load issue or other), but there is most definitely a bug somewhere, since the feature isn't working [as documented](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the daily scripts have been timing out―including the one that would fix this particular issue, meaning that some questions have not been roomba'd properly.

We are looking at fixing those timeouts―that will sort out all discrepancies.

Comment: Do we have to wait 6-8 to be sure?

Comment: @Braiam - fraid so. No estimate on when this will be fixed - we try something and wait for the next day... very slow feedback loop there.

Comment: post the sql code in main :p

Comment: @Drew - not sure how that will help if the issue is with locking caused by concurrent access ;)

Comment: that's our specialty :p